# OnBackPressed is not being called?

Tags: android

I have override the `OnBackPressed` function inside my activity, but it's not being called. On other activities it's working fine.
Here is my method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Log.e("back",""+1); 
    UserPage.getstate().finish();
    Intent i=new Intent(CreateGroup.this,UserPage.class);
    i.putExtra("title11","dd");
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
```

This method is not being called, and the default `OnBackPresssed` is called every time i press the back button.

Comment: What is "UserPage.getstate().finish();" doing?

Comment: you got this Log.e("back",""+1);  in log??

Comment: I have used a static function in UserPage to get the state of the activty and then i am finishing it.

Comment: @Dhawal No i am not getting it

Comment: This is clearly a design issue, whenever a user press the back button he will assume that he is  navigating back to the previous page,so if you want to send data between activity u should use start Activity for result to get the data for CreateGroup.

Comment: I am not sending any data, just restarting the previous activity after the back press. That title11 value is just arbitary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this code

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Log.e("back",""+1); 
        UserPage.getstate().finish();
        Intent i=new Intent(CreateGroup.this,UserPage.class);
        i.putExtra("title11","dd");
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I am using onStop and onRestart methods in the UserPage Activity. Does that have anything to do with this?

Comment: Apart form changing the activity, do you see the logging?? Or the back button is not work too? What is you android version btw?

Comment: Try to delete all the code inside the if block, to check if there is the problem of the back button or other mistake :D

Comment: Hey i just cleaned the project and now it's working fine. Don't know what was wrong? :/ Thnx for your reply :)

Answer (score 8):

Had a similar issue.  The problem for me was in my override of onKeyDown() hiding the KEYCODE_BACK keydown events.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried this? ,

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        // do something on back pressed.


        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Log.e("back",""+1); 
        UserPage.getstate().finish();
        Intent i=new Intent(CreateGroup.this,UserPage.class);
        i.putExtra("title11","dd");
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```